# Azure Load Balancer Alert rules

Tags: azure, load-balancing, alert

On Azure portal, On a load balancer object, I see that there is a way to enable diagnostics and create alerts that will be sent to the audit log. How can I then send these alerts to a Webhook ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For many resource monitoring scenarios, you would create an *alert rule* and wire up your webhook there.  This is not available though for an Azure Load Balancer.

As an alternative, I would suggest creating an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) that gets triggered when an alert is written to the blob storage account you selected for the load balancer diagnostics.  Inside the Azure Function, add your code to invoke the webhook.  An example of how to bind an Azure Function to your blob storage account is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).

For the path setting, you can monitor the `insights-logs-loadbalanceralertevent` container.  This will trigger your function every time an alert is recorded.